# Split file after a string

Tags: awk

I have a file in aix which I want to split after the following string:

"Snapshot timestamp                         = 11/25/2014 16:00:00"

I tried using command below however I get error due to the space in the string.

```
awk '/YOUR_TEXT_HERE/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt
```

It would also helpful if I can get a syntax to split data 'before' the string as well.

Comment: The spaces in that string would not cause any problem for being inserted literally into that awk command (in place of `YOUR_TEXT_HERE`) but the slashes would. You would need to escape them. That being said if that's a literal string and that's the entire line I would use `$0 == "YOUR_TEXT_HERE"` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "split after..."? Show sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for your response. 
Perhaps I have picked up an incorrect command hence the confusion.
By 'after' I meant below:

Original File

A
B
c
D
Snapshot timestamp = 11/25/2014 16:00:00
E 
F
G

'After' should give me file:

E
F
G

'Before' should give me file:

A
B
C
D

I am okay for 'Snapshot' string to be included/excluded in the files

Comment: Before or after depends on whether you print the current line and then change to a new file or change to a new file and then print the line. Which you want just changes where you `n++`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not spaces it is the "/".

Have you protected the "/" in the date?

```
(/...11\/25\/2014.../)
```

(with that it is working for me)

```
awk '/Snapshot timestamp = 11\/25\/2014 16:00:00/ {n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt
```

As @Etan Reisner point out,

```
awk '$0 == "Snap..." {n++; next } {print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt
```

is a better solutions (you don't have to protect the regex operators). The "next" instruction will "remove" the timestamp from the output files.

If you plan to do that again in the future I suggest a awk scritp:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN                      { n =1                  }
/Snapshot timestamp = /    { n++; next             }
                           { print >"out" n ".txt" }
```

Usage

```
awk -f awkscript  final.txt
```

or

```
awkscript  final.txt    (after chmod...)
```

Comment: thank you: (the backslash were hidden by the wiki). I will improve the answer.